# How to push records from one grid to another grid in Angular 6

Tags: html, angular, kendo-ui, angular6

I have two grids one is dataListGridData and alldataListGridData, in both grids, I have data now one grid I have remove and other on I am having to add button if click on remove data should be used to alldataListGridData grid and if clicked on Add button selected record should push to the dataList grid. How can I do this?

```css
export class SaveObjectComponent implements OnInit {
  public dataListGridData: GridDataResult;
  public alldataListGridData: GridDataResult;
  principleId: string;
  dataId: any;
  dataList: any[] = [];
  alldataList: any[] = [];
  sort: SortDescriptor[] = [{
    field: 'name',
    dir: 'asc'
  }];
  state: State = {
    skip: 0,
    take: 0,
    sort: [{
      field: 'name',
      dir: 'asc'
    }]
  };
  public stateAll: State = {
    skip: 0,
    take: 0,
  };

  constructor(private dataservice: DataService) {
    this.dataId = 'aabb2b4a-bfa6-4ca4-a911-8d89dca7a575';
  }


  ngOnInit() {
 
    this.refresh();
  }
  
  async refresh() {
    this.updatedSearchesList = [];
    const search = await this.worksheetService.getAvailableSearches(this.dataId, this.principleId);
    if (!search.hasError && search.result) {
      this.dataList = search.result;
      this.dataListGridData = {
        data: this.dataList.slice(this.state.skip, this.state.take),
        total: this.dataList.length
      };
    }
    if (this.dataList.length > 0) {
      this.dataList.forEach(element => {
        this.updatedSearchesList.push(element.resourceId);
      });
    }
    this.getAvailableSearch();
  }

  async getAvailableSearch() {
    console.log(this.principleId);
    const allSearch = await this.worksheetService.getAvailableSearches(this.worksheetId, this.principleId);
    console.log(allSearch);
    this.alldataList = allSearch.result;
    this.alldataListGridData = {
      data: this.alldataList.slice(this.stateAll.skip, this.stateAll.take),
      total: this.alldataList.length
    };
  }
  onRemoveRowClicked(object: any) {
    debugger;
    console.log(object);
    const objectIndex = this.dataList.indexOf(object.resourceId);
    console.log(objectIndex);
    if (objectIndex === -1) {
      object.isClicked = true;
      this.dataList.splice(objectIndex);
      console.log( this.dataList.splice(objectIndex));
    } else {
      object.isClicked = false;
      this.dataList.push(object);
    }
  }
  onAddRowClicked(rowAdd: any) {
    console.log(rowAdd);
    const objectIndex = this.a.indexOf(rowAdd);
    if (objectIndex === -1) {
      rowAdd.isClicked = true;
      this.alldataList.push(rowAdd);
      this.alldataListGridData = null;
      this.alldataListGridData = {
        data: rowAdd.splice(this.stateAll.skip, this.stateAll.take),
        total: rowAdd.length
      };
      console.log(this.alldataList);
    } else {
      rowAdd.isClicked = false;
      this.alldataList.splice(objectIndex, 1);
    }
  }
  public dataStateChange(state: DataStateChangeEvent): void {
    this.state = state;
    this.dataListGridData = process(this.dataList, this.state);
  }
  public dataStateChanges(state: DataStateChangeEvent): void {
    this.state = state;
    this.alldataListGridData = process(this.alldataList, this.stateAll);
  }
  public sortChange(sort: SortDescriptor[]): void {
    this.sort = sort;
  }
  public sortChanges(sort: SortDescriptor[]): void {
    this.sort = sort;
  }

  
}
```

```html
<kendo-grid [data]="worksheetGridData" [filter]="state.filter" filterable="menu" [sortable]="true" [sort]="sort"
      (sortChange)="sortChange($event)" (dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)" 
       [resizable]="true" [scrollable]="'scrollable'" [height]="300">
      <kendo-grid-column field="name" title="Object Name" [width]="165">
      </kendo-grid-column>
      <kendo-grid-column field="categoryName" title="Category" [width]="150">
      </kendo-grid-column>
      <kendo-grid-command-column title="Remove" width="80">
        <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
          <button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="onRemoveRowClicked(dataItem)" [ngClass]="{'selectedRemoveButton': dataItem.isClicked}">
            <mat-icon>remove_circle</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </ng-template>
      </kendo-grid-command-column>
    </kendo-grid>





<kendo-grid [data]="recentWorksheetGridData" [filter]="state.filter" filterable="menu" [sortable]="true" [sort]="sort"
      (sortChange)="sortChanges($event)" (dataStateChange)="dataStateChanges($event)"
       [resizable]="true" [scrollable]="'scrollable'" [height]="300" >
      <kendo-grid-column field="name" title="Object Name" [width]="165">
      </kendo-grid-column>
      <kendo-grid-column field="categoryName" title="Category" [width]="150">
 
      <kendo-grid-command-column title="Add" width="80">
        <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
          <button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="onAddRowClicked(dataItem)" [ngClass]="{'selectedAddButton': dataItem.isClicked}">
            <mat-icon>add_circle</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </ng-template>
      </kendo-grid-command-column>
    </kendo-grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the grids themselves are just UI components that present the data, they do not hold the data. So, you don't actually move a row from one grid to the other, you move it from the data structure that's backing one array to the data structure backing the other grid, and then both grids will re+render the changed data.

So, you'll need to write code that moves data between your 'worksheetGridData' and 'recentWorksheetGridData' structures.